# How to return file image name in database after upload in Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

The image uploads fine, it moves to the required folder, but the path name is not being returned into my database, it stays null

Posts Controller

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $fileName = $request->file('image');
        $file_name = $fileName->getClientOriginalName();
        $formFields['image'] = $request->file('image')->store('img','public');
    }

Posts::create([
        'title' => $request->post('title'),
        'sub_title' => $request->post('sub_title'),
        'tags' => $request->post('tags'),
        'content' => $request->post('content'),
        'featured' => ($request->has('featured')) ? true : false,
    ]);
```

Image upload input

```
<div class="mb-2">
 <label for="image" class="mb-1">Image</label>
  <input type="file" class="w-100" name="image">
   @error('image')
    <p class="mt-1 text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
   @enderror
</div>
```

Comment: You don't appear to be saving it to the database anywhere in the code you've supplied?

Comment: I mentioned it's being saved to the required folder, or maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Saving the image to a folder on your server doesn't automatically save the filename/path to your database. You still need to do that part yourself.

Comment: I followed this tutorial, when the path name did not show up in my db, I tried to do it myself with no luck https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYyJ4PuL4pY&t=10607s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add filename field in your table, the file moves to the required folder but after that you must assign the filename in a filed in Posts table like this :

```
Posts::create([
    'title' => $request->post('title'),
    'sub_title' => $request->post('sub_title'),
    'tags' => $request->post('tags'),
    'content' => $request->post('content'),
    'featured' => ($request->has('featured')) ? true : false,
    'filename' => $file_name   // add this line
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code used at [this timestamp](https://youtu.be/MYyJ4PuL4pY?t=10461). Notice that he is adding the image from the `$request` to his `$formFields` array which is an array of validated `$request` fields before passing the `$formFields` array to the `create` method on the object. You need to replicate that process.

```
$formFields = [
    'title' => $request->post('title'),
    'sub_title' => $request->post('sub_title'),
    'tags' => $request->post('tags'),
    'content' => $request->post('content'),
    'featured' => ($request->has('featured')) ? true : false,
];

if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $formFields['image'] = $request->file('image')->store('img','public');
}

Posts::create($formFields);
```

Side note, I have omitted `$request` input validation but you'll want to perform validation on the `$request` inputs. Never trust input.